# Listing full address path with Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that searches through all files in a directory using something like this;

```
Get-ChildItem $location -recurse | select-string -pattern $pattern | select-object Path, FileName, LineNumber > C:\test.txt
```

The problem I have is that the Path gets enshortened, like this;

> C:\program files\new folder\new f...

How can I get it to display the full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so it's clear why you saw the truncating behavior, the default formatter picked is `Format-Table` which divies up the current host width into three equally sized columns and if the data is wider than that it gets truncated.  Another way of doing this:

```
gci $location -r | select-string $pattern | 
  Format-Table Path, FileName, LineNumber -Auto | 
  Out-File C:\test.txt -width 512
```

Answer (score 0):

> Export-Csv

made it possible, thanks to BartekB and denty on freenode's #powershell